# Explode List containing many dictionaries in Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, data-cleaning

I am having a dataset which look like follows(in dataframe):

```
**_id** **paper_title**   **references**                                                                  **full_text**
 1         XYZ              [{'abc':'something','def':'something'},{'def':'something'},...many others]       something
 2         XYZ              [{'abc':'something','def':'something'},{'def':'something'},...many others]       something
 3         XYZ              [{'abc':'something'},{'def':'something'},...many others]                         something
```

Expected:

```
**_id** **paper_title**   **abc**    **def**                               **full_text**
   1         XYZ          something  something                               something               
                          something  something
                          .    
                          .
                         (all the dic in list with respect to_id column)
   2         XYZ          something  something                               something               
                          something  something
                          .    
                          .
                         (all the dic in list with respect to_id column)
```

I have tried `df['column_name'].apply(pd.Series).apply(pd.Series)` to split the list and dictionaries into columns of dataframe but doesn't help as it didn't split dictionaries.

**First row of my dataframe:**
[df.head(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbquL.png)

Comment: its better if you can post the result of `df.head().to_dict()` of the sample dataframe you've shared , same with the expected output , so we can replicate the question, thanks

Comment: You are going to an answer FAST if you provide code containing your DataFrame that someone can stick into a console and work with.

Comment: @Karthik V I have added the screenshot of original dataframe. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of Documentation reading of pandas, I found the [explode method](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) applying with [apply(pd.Series)](https://www.mikulskibartosz.name/how-to-split-a-list-inside-a-dataframe-cell-into-rows-in-pandas/) is the easiest of what I was looking for in the question.

Here is the Code:

```
df = df.explode('reference')
```

# It explodes the lists to rows of the subset columns

```
df = df['reference'].apply(pd.Series).merge(df, left_index=True, right_index=True, how ='outer')
```

# split a list inside a Dataframe cell into rows and merge with original dataframe like (AUB) in set theory

> Sidenote: while merging look for unique values in column as there will many columns with duplicated values

I hope this helps someone with dataframe/Series with columns having list containing multiple dictionaries and want to split list of multiple dictionaries key to new column with values as their rows.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your original DataFrame is a list of dictionaries with one key:value pair and a key named 'reference':

```
print(df)                                                                                                                                
   id paper_title                                         references       full_text
0   1         xyz  [{'reference': 'description1'}, {'reference': ...       some text
1   2         xyz  [{'reference': 'descriptiona'}, {'reference': ...       more text
2   3         xyz  [{'reference': 'descriptioni'}, {'reference': ...  even more text
```

Then you can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to separate out your references with their index:

```
df1 = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(i) for i in df['references']], keys = df.index).reset_index(level=1,drop=True)
print(df1)                                                                                                                               
        reference
0    description1
0    description2
0    description3
1    descriptiona
1    descriptionb
1    descriptionc
2    descriptioni
2   descriptionii
2  descriptioniii
```

Then use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to join the columns back together on their index:

```
df = df.drop('references', axis=1).join(df1).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)                                                                                                                                
   id paper_title       full_text       reference
0   1         xyz       some text    description1
1   1         xyz       some text    description2
2   1         xyz       some text    description3
3   2         xyz       more text    descriptiona
4   2         xyz       more text    descriptionb
5   2         xyz       more text    descriptionc
6   3         xyz  even more text    descriptioni
7   3         xyz  even more text   descriptionii
8   3         xyz  even more text  descriptioniii
```

Comment: Thanks @dkhara I think it would work but i found the easiest way.

Comment: on joining dataframe, the values of reference column are NaN for whole column(https://imgur.com/MrmXx3f). I don't know what is happening. And can you please explain what is going on here `[pd.DataFrame(i) for i in df['references']`?

Comment: The `[pd.DataFrame(i) for i in df['references']` is an example of list comprehension, where each of those references in curly brackets are turned into DataFrames. Then, those DataFrames are concatenated using [pandas.concat](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html)